# Logistic regression with same response?

Tags: regression, probability, logistic

For binary logistic regression, the responses are either 0 or 1. But what if I only want to predicate the probability of response 1?

Let's say I want to predicate how likely it will rain. I recorded in the past some features like temperature, air pressure when it rains. But I never record anything when it doesn't rain.

So I only have response 1 in my data, there is no 0, how I can train the model with logistic regression?

Comment: Well, you can't. Without any records on the alternative outcome, your response variable cannot be modelled as a Bernoulli event.

Comment: so is there any other algorithms I can use for such problem? I cannot image how to record "not rain", I mean "not rain" is not an event at all.

Comment: There are [one-class classification algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification) that would probably fit your scenario but I have no personal experience with them to guide you through. For the record, you would record data for "not rain" the same way you would do for "yes rain", e.g. temperature during not-rain, air pressure during not-rain, etc.

Comment: @Digio thank you for your answer, I will check the link you send. About the "not rain" record, how often i should record such event? I mean if the data contains too many 0 or 1, will it influence the logistic regression result?

Comment: There's no golden rule for this but you should have sufficient data for both outcomes - the more the better.

Comment: If you look at the page @digio linked to, you will see that it isn't really a good solution.  And it's not needed.  You have "not rain" on any day when it didn't rain. You should record the same data for those days.